# How do i change color of Jtree based on my dynamic changing Jtree for java desktop application

Tags: java, swing, applet, jtree

Everyone, I'm making desk app with `JPanel` and `JFrame`. Here is my tree structure:

**Default tree**

```
@Root
 |-L1B  (node-1)
 |-L2A (node-2)
 |-L1A (node-3)
```

After this i'm reading a file (let's suppose two values: `value1` and `value2`) and add leaf data.

So, I'de like to change the color like this:

```
@Root
 |**-L1B**  (node-1)(with green color)
    | value1(with green color)
    | value2(with green color)
 |-L2A (node-2)
 |-L1A (node-3)
```

`value1` value might be 60s, meaning that for 60s it will in be green and then become red.

```
@Root
 |**-L1B**  (node-1)(with green color)
    | value1(with green red)
    | value2(with green color)
 |-L2A (node-2)
 |-L1A (node-3)
```

And after 60s, `value2` value might be 60s more than `value1`, so that for 60s it will be green and then turn red.

```
@Root
 |**-L1B**  (node-1)(with green color)
    | value1(with green red)
    | value2(with green color)
 |-L2A (node-2)
 |-L1A (node-3)
```

So, basically I want the hierarchy of running processes. When it is running, the color should be green and then it will change to another color.

Comment: I would take a look at the [Java Tutorials - How to Use Trees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a custom rendered.

To do that, take your `JTree` and call the `setCellRenderer()` method passin your renderer.

A basic renderer is an inheritance of `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`. The method that returns the rendering is `getTreeCellRendererComponent()`.

Unfortunately, your question is very vague, so I can't give a more specific example, so a generic example would be:

```
JTree paintedTree = new JTree();
paintedTree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Component renderedItem = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        if (((YourClass)value).getTime() > 60) {
            renderedItem.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        return renderedItem;
    }
});
```

Note that this answer is strictly from the rendering of colors' point of view. The code for determining if the process is running was simplified by `(((YourClass)value).getTime() > 60)` to keep the answer in focus.

**Also, check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaCustomRenderer.htm) page. It might help you with your pursuit.**

Comment: public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {

// code

}
 i have crated my own render class , and its perfectly run ..

my quesiotn is how i call again and again this class and its getTreeCellRendererComponent() with it's different changing values .

Comment: @Krunal In this case, the `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` function will be called every time you repaint the container. So, I would call `repaint()` whenever a process exits, this would trigger the rendering, and then you can test if the process is running or not, and display the proper color. I hope this helps. Let me know if this is what you meant. Or, create a new question with the proper code, so I can understand better what you mean.

Comment: i don't know how  pass value in the customized renderer class so that  i can just simple coompare my passed value with getTreeCellRendererComponent  methods value param .

or is there any method that will pass my arguments to thisgetTreeCellRendererComponent(  ) method.